# onmouseover for link_to image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a linked image_tag that I would like to change images on mouseover.  I thought the following would work, but the image is not switching on mouseover:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("new_step.png"),new_project_step_path(@project), :class=> "newStep", :onmouseover => "new_step_highlighted.png"%>
```

I also tried editing the css, but this unfortunately didn't work either:

```
.newStep{
    background: url('../assets/new_step_highlighted.png');
}

.newStep:hover{
    background: url('../assets/new_step_highlighted.png');
}
```

For both cases, only the image "new_step.png" appears.  How would I fix this?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With css only, you need to have both images used as the background property of the `link_to` tag (actually the `a` tag). With what you wrote, you had one image "hard-coded" into the dom with an `image_tag` and you tried to change the link's background property cause `newStep` is actually the `link_to` class.

```
<%= link_to "Text", new_project_step_path(@project), :class => "newStep" %>
```

Then the css (btw, you don't need to prepend ".." to the path to your assets folder) :

```
.newStep {
    display: inline-block;
    width: your-image-width;
    height: your-image-height;
    background: url('/assets/new_step.png');
}

.newStep:hover {
    background: url('/assets/new_step_highlighted.png');
}
```

**Here the fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/km6Sp/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just tried this, and no images appears when I load the page.  I used the chrome inspector and found that the image path was actually assets/new_step.png, so I changed my css file to url('/assets/new_step.png"), but the image is still not appearing...

Comment: Is this a typo in your image url path with the single quote at the beginning and the double quote at the end ? In the inspector, when you click on the image link in the css, is the image appearing ?

Comment: Whoops, yes, that was a typo; there should be double quotes on both ends.  When I click the "new_step.png" image link in the css, new_step.png does appear.  It does not appear that new_step_highlighted.png is loaded on page load.  Also, although the image link in the css does appear to work, the image itself does not appear on the page.

Comment: What do you mean "It does not appear that new_step_highlighted.png is loaded on page load." ? Is this image appearing when you click on the css inspector link ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  When I open up the inspector in Chrome and go over to the "Resources" tab, the image "new_step.png" appears under my images folder.  It says that the url for the image is: http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/new_step.png.  If I go to the link http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/new_step_highlighted.png, the highlighted image appears.  However, this file does not appear in my "images" folder in the inspector.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it without modifying CSS, with less code:

```
<%= link_to some_route_path do
    image_tag("find.png", onmouseover: "this.src='#{asset_path('find_sel.png')}'", onmouseout: "this.src='#{asset_path('find.png')}'")
end %>
```

Comment: This is old-school obtrusive JS, and probably should be avoided, but in a pinch this is what the `:mouseover` option to `image_tag` used to do up until Rails 4. Even if I'm not using it, it works, so you deserve an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Sparda's response was correct except that my image path was actually just "/assets/new_step.png".  The images weren't appearing because of an issue with my CSS file.